# T-SQL : count occurrences per unique substring in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to count occurrences per unique substring in a column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(code, 3) 
FROM table-with-codes
```

Output:

```
code
------------------
VJCrandomthings
PASrandomthings
CAArandomthings
PASrandomthings2
PASrandomthings3
```

Expected output:

```
caa 1
pas 3
vjc 1
```

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(code, 3)) 
FROM table-with-codes
```

but that returns 3 as result.

Comment: I tried SELECT count (DISTINCT left(code, 3) ) FROM table-with-codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the extracted 3 letters in the `select` statement and `Group by`.

**Query**

```
Select left(code, 3) as code3, count(left(code, 3)) as cnt
From tablename
Group by left(code, 3)
Order by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `count` with `group by`

```
select Left(code,3), Count(*)
from [table-with-codes]
group by Left(code,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with using `left` but instead of `distinct` you should `group by`

```
declare @table_with_codes table (code varchar(50))
insert into @table_with_codes values ('VJCrandomthings'), ('PASrandomthings'), ('CAArandomthings'), ('PASrandomthings2'), ('PASrandomthings3')

select left(code, 3) as code_3, 
       count(*) as cnt
from   @table_with_codes 
group by left(code, 3)
```

**how this works**
By using the group by you can count all rows that are grouped (and thus only returned once in the result), in this case all rows with the same value in lef(col, 3)

The result will be

```
code_3  cnt
------  ---
CAA      1
PAS      3
VJC      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like having LEFT(code, 3) appear more than once in the query. To improve maintainability and readability I'd refactor it using CROSS APPLY, like this :

```
SELECT subcode, COUNT(*)
FROM table-with-codes
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(code, 3)) AS T(subcode)
GROUP BY subcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Common Transaction Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to avoid mentioning left function two times:

```
create table [table-with-codes] (code nvarchar(100))
go
insert into [table-with-codes] values('VJCrandomthings'),('PASrandomthings'),('CAArandomthings'),('PASrandomthings2'),('PASrandomthings3');


with cte as (select LEFT(code,3) mycode from [table-with-codes])
select mycode,count(1) N from cte group by mycode
```

[image]